# Koala gem: how to update page info?

Tags: ruby, koala, koala-gem

I have the page's auth token. I want to update my page attributes like `is_webhooks_subscribed`. I can do it in Graph API Explorer with no problem.

[Here is documentation on Page updating endpoint](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/#Updating)

How do I do that using Graph API in Koala gem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up reading gem source code. Found the `api` method, that is commented: *You'll rarely need to call this method directly*.

Solution:

```
graph = Koala::Facebook::API.new(page_auth_token)
graph.api('me', { is_webhooks_subscribed: true }, 'post')
```